# How Do I Get a subvector from a vector?

Tags: c++, logic, stdvector

How do i access 1,2,10 from the below vector?

```
D = [[1, 2, 10], [2, 3, 20], [2, 5, 25]]

int i=B[i][0]-1;
int j <= B[i][1]-1;
```

Was Solving a Problem, I Had to use them in a for loop to check for the answer. Can Anyone help me out

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include an actual [mcve].

Comment: I don't see any `std::vector`s in your question. It's totally unclear what you're asking. Please [edit] and clarify. And what is `B` anyway??

Comment: write a loop that accesses `B[0][ i ]`. Otherwise it is completely unclear what help you need. Please show real code

Comment: D is synantically incorrect in holding a vector of vectors. It should use `{` instead of `[`

Comment: What are the expected values for `i` and `j`?

Comment: Please paste your C++ code, not a metacode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> d = { {1, 2, 10}, {2, 3, 20}, {2, 5, 25} };

  auto subvector = d[0];

  for (auto& value : subvector)
  {
    std::cout << value << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << "\n";

  // or (poor solution)

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    std::cout << subvector[i] << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << "\n";

  // or even

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    std::cout << d[0][i] << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: why copy the subvector? and better `for (const auto& value` or just `for (auto value`

Comment: @idclev463035818 I know, it's just for clarity. The OP really seems confused